# SSH.NET library encode the file name

Tags: c#, encoding, ssh, sftp, ssh.net

I must download a file using SSH.NET library. After I download a file I must delete the remote file. 
Everything works but the file name is encoded. I mean that for example, if I have a file named `New file`, I download/upload a file named `New%20file`. Now, if I download/upload the new file I obtain `New%25%20file` and again `New%252520file`... and so on...
This is very problematic. How can I avoid to change the file name after I download it?

Here the code I am using to download:

```
string fileName = base.Uri.GetFileName();
string fullPath = Path.Combine(pathFolder, fileName);

using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(
              new PasswordConnectionInfo(
                    base.Uri.Host, SftpFlowGateway.CONST_PORT_NUMBER,
                    base.Credential.UserName,
                    base.Credential.Password))
      )
{
    client.Connect();

    using (FileStream fileStreamToDownload = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        client.DownloadFile(base.Uri.LocalPath, fileStreamToDownload);
    }

    client.Disconnect();
}
```

EDIT:

`base.Uri` is just defined as follow:

```
private Uri _uri;
public Uri Uri 
{
    get { return _uri; }
    protected set { _uri = value; } 
}
```

And the GetFileName method is:

```
public static string GetFileName(this Uri path)
{
    return path.Segments.Last();
}
```

When I debug, I can see that the properties of the class Uri have the correct value... It is not encoded

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a stream you have created yourself (`new FileStream`) to the SSH.NET. The library does not even know it's a file it is writing to, nor its name. So it's not the library that URL-encodes the file name. It has to be URL-encoded in the `fullPath` variable already.

It's the [`Uri.AbsolutePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.absolutepath) and [`Uri.Segments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments) that return URL-encoded path. That's how the [`System.Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri) class works. I assume you use the constructor overload [`Uri(string uriString)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor#system-uri-ctor(system-string)).

Use the static method [`Uri.UnescapeDataString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.unescapedatastring) to reverse encoding done by the [`Uri` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor#system-uri-ctor(system-string)).

*Note the obsoleted constructor overload [`Uri(string uriString, bool dontEscape)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor#system-uri-ctor(system-string-system-boolean)).*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the SSH.Net library simply URL encodes the file names.

I suppose you could rename the file after you've downloaded it using the System.Web.UrlDecode method?

Or UrlEncode the filename when you upload.

Unfortunately, I haven't used the library myself but you could help further by letting us know if the name change occurs on download or upload or both.

EDIT:
As martin mentioned, its not the library doing any encoding.

I've just tried it myself.

```
string fileName = "file with spaces.txt";
using (Stream outputFile = File.OpenWrite(localDir + "\\" + fileName))
{
    sftpClient.DownloadFile(fileName, outputFile);
}
```

The created file is also named "file with spaces.txt" though that would've been the case anyway since it was created via the stream.

Comment: Hi, the name change occurs both on download and on upload. I think I can use UrlEncode/UrlDecode on remote file.. but, on download the problem is locally..